# Adding a view and then properly routing it in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Ok everyone, 
i am using rails 4.2.0
so i have created three scaffolds but needed to add an additional view to one of my models.

I have a Site and Resident model and what i am looking to accomplish is to create a resident thst ties directly back to the site from a link on the site show page.

In my site controller i have the following.

```
def new_site_resident
  @site.residents.create(resident_params)
end
```

AND

```
def resident_params
  params.require(:resident).permit(:site_id, :unit_number, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :dob)
end
```

im my routes folder i have

```
get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"
```

and have tried get "/sites/new_site_resident

when i use the get "/sites/new_site_resident it comes back with this error:

> Couldn't find Site with 'id'=new_site_resident

^^ i am sure this is telling me it is looking for a site with that as the id.

when i use get "/sites/id/new_site_resident" in routes.rb and then try to go to: 
http://localhost:3000/sites/1/new_site_resident it gives the error of:

> No route matches [GET] "/sites/1/new_site_resident"

not too sure where to go with this? but as i said before i want to be able to look at the site and then be able to directly create a resident in that link that ties back to the site without having to manually enter the site id as the end uses would know that the site id would be.

Current routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  resources :sites
  resources :vehicles
  resources :residents

  get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Comment: Why didn't you try getting `/sites/1/new_site_resident` when you have `get 'sites/:id/new_site_resident'` in your routes? It should work this way (unless there are other routes interfering).

Comment: I just tried to go to http://localhost:3000/sites/1/new_site_resident and it gives me No route matches [GET] "/sites/1/new_site_resident" as the error.. when i try to rake routes now it gives me the following :ArgumentError: 'sites/:id' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. but i have modified my controller to allow for this by adding the def new_site_resident
  @site.residents.create(resident_params)
end

Comment: Please show current content of your `routes.rb`.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :sites
  resources :vehicles
  resources :residents

  get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" } 
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.

Comment: ill edit the original post so its easier to see.

Comment: How is your controller named?

Comment: im using the sites_controller i also have a residents_controller but want to write to the residents table through the site id

Comment: either way thanks a bunch!! i messed around with the before_actions and got it going! much thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create route to your action, you can use `resources`:

```
resources :sites do
  member do
    get :new_site_resident
  end
end
```

then you can remove

```
get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"
```

Comment: so then ill completely remove the get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"
 from routes,rb and replace it with the above?

Comment: beautiful that resolved that problem! now ill play around with the uindefined method problem.. hahaha cheers!

Comment: can i ask another question of you?

Comment: this is a new error that pops up now undefined method `resident' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #22):
20
21
22
23
24
25
              

  def new_site_resident
    @site.resident.create(new_site_resident_params[:site_id])
  end

  # GET /sites/1/edit

Comment: Why don't you add another question in StackOverflow?

Comment: i am too new it says i can only post once every 90 min. only been here for about 2 days.

Comment: @ShawnWilson BTW, it's quite easy, you didn't set `@site` instance variable, so it's `nil`.

Comment: so thats where im lost   @site.resident.create(new_site_resident_params[:site_id]) it is this line that needs modification? im still a noob with ROR im sorry..

Comment: @ShawnWilson Not exactly, you need to set `@site` (probably using `@site = Site.find(params[:id])` or `@site = current_user.sites.find(params[:id])` or if you have `find_site` or similar method in your `before_filter`, make it work also before `new_site_resident` action. Plus, I advice going through some basic tutorials.

Comment: ive done the treehouse tracks but loosing it here now.. hahah

Comment: and i have 'def set_site' @site = Site.find(params[:id]) end as a private function.

Comment: @ShawnWilson So you have to modify `before_filter` so it also runs before your `new_site_resident` action.

Comment: i added: before_action :site_resident, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] and it links to the page ill add the form to it and see if it takes it.

Comment: `before_action :set_site, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :new_site_resident]` or `before_action :set_site, except: [:index, :new, :create]`. Plus I *really* advice you to go through valuable tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Just move

```
get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"
```

line to the start of the routes file. File should look like

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'
  get "/sites/:id/new_site_resident"
  resources :sites
  resources :vehicles
  resources :residents

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

Or try member routes to define this route like

```
 resources :sites do
   member do
     get :new_site_resident
   end
 end
```